# Can flash download html from random webpage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, cross-domain, sandbox

I have given up on trying to get the source of a webpage (I don't own this server) in AS3. All it does is throw an sandbox violation error (2048). So far I have come to a conclusion that the only solutions possible are:

- Make my web server serve the content to the swf.
- Make a proxy server for the swf with crossdomain.xml.

Somehow, both the options are being rejected by my seniors & I am being pushed for a better solution.

I don't have any idea if anything else is possible, does anyone here have one??

---

**EDIT :**
Maybe some hack where **'A'** may not need the policy file to communicate directly with **'B'** :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple PHP proxy is the easiest way:

```
<?php
  echo system ("curl \"".$_GET["url"]."\"");
?>
```

And call it with

```
http://www.yourserver.com/pathtoyourscript/proxy.php?url=http://www.yoururl.com
```

not tested, but in general it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for any other solution (if exists) other than a server side...

Comment: If it only has to run on a local machine, then you don't have to deal with crossdomain.xml. Or you can create an AIR app. Otherwise I think thats the only solution

Comment: Read about crossdomain.xml. You can't do what you want without some sort of a hack: JS, proxy server, etc.

Comment: @23tux How things can be approached without a server side implementation using adobe air?

Comment: I'm not sure if Air has this sandbox issues, because the crossdomain and cross origin resource sharing restrictions origin from the webbrowser in which your SWF is running

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you run your app in browser, I can suggest downloading HTML with javascript (e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest`), and then passing it to your app via `ExternalInterface`. I'm not sure that it's better then solutions you posted. Anyway it's client-side hack and different from yours.

**UPD:** another way is to create an invisible frame and do
`document.getElementByID('frameID').src=url;` there, after that pass `document.getElementByID('frameID').innerHtml` to swf with ExternalInterface

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` has the same restrictions actionscript has. it's only possible within the same domain.

Comment: Besides I was really after some uncommon trick someone might have come across. Well I guess the chances are slight...

Comment: @loxxy,proposed another variant ;)

Comment: Using the iframe approach would still have cross domains security issues.

Comment: @walkietokyo You are right. We can't get the inner content with the innerHTML attribute...

Answer (score 1):

AS3 has a few ways of loading html from web pages.  The most convenient is probably to use a `URLLoader.load()` function.

```
    const targetURL:String = "www.example.com"

    var quest:URLRequest = new URLRequest()
    quest.url = targetURL

    var oader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
    oader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doSomething)
    oader.load(quest)
```

For more information:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

If done correctly, this should load the web page's html as a string.

If I understand your problem correctly, this probably isn't working.  So of course, there are a few work-arounds you could use.

I remember in an old project I was doing with a similar obstacle, my solution was to have an external SWF written in `AS2` (hosted on another server, my FTP server).  My main SWF loaded the AS2 SWF using `Loader.load()`.  Communicating between the two SWFs using `LoacalConnection`s [(link)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html).  For some reason, the server I had uploaded my SWF to didn't allow AS3's `URLLoader.load()` but allowed AS2's `sendAndLoad()`.

Another work-around I used, I used an external AS3 SWF, for a similar reason.

I recommend you experiment with various methods, your specific work-around may not be what I have recommended, however my recommendations may point you in the right direction.

And of course the good thing with my work-around is that your seniors won't notice a difference.  The main SWF will be hosted on the same server, and will function as intended, with a minimal increase to load time.

Comment: Thanks, but even loading an external swf requires permission from the target server given by the crossdomain.xml file. Besides, doing it is same as using a proxy server.