# AS3 security error 2048 on socket connection

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I have a simple IRC socket that is used to communicate with servers for a web-based IRC client. Unfortunately, attempting to connect to a network results in a security error. I read up on sandboxes and their appropriate permissions, and then used `Security.sandboxType` to get the sandbox of my socket, which came up as `remote`. After reviewing the documentation, I still don't fully understand how I can enable my socket to connect to a remote IRC server. I tried `Security.allowDomain`, but that didn't do anything. What else is there?

Comment: You trying in browser or stand alone fp ? If in local - You add this swf file to trusted exceptions in global settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error is simply because you are directly trying to connect to IRC. You will need to use some sort of proxy server to get your request through.

Read about [Adobe's security policy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html). I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174157/can-flash-download-html-from-random-webpage) on SO just a day back..

For connecting to IRC, perhaps the following could help:

> Flash does not allow you to connect to servers that are outside the so-called sandbox of your Flash application. You are of course able to extend that sandbox by using Security.loadPolicyFile...([link](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2005/10/26/how-to-use-sockets-in-actionscript3/))

Comment: I don't have the resources to proxy every request through my server. Is there no way to make the client connect if the IRC server doesn't have a policy file?

Comment: I doubt if there some other way, considering the responses I myself got regarding this question.